# Faux-server dosnt work corectly with require.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js, requirejs

I have some Backbone Model structure in my project. Each of this model need to fetch or save and I decided to use a **faux-server** to mocks the server-side. In my projekt i also use a **require.js** and with it I have a problem.

Example:

```
define([
    'models/billings/details',
    'models/statistics/abonent',

    'mocks/billings/details',
    'mocks/statistics/abonent'
], function(detailsModel, statisticsAbonentModel) {

      var detailsM = new detailsModel();
      detailsM.fetch({async: false});

      var statisticsAbonentM = new statisticsAbonentModel();
      statisticsAbonentM.fetch({async: false});
});
```

When I define more then one mocks - only the last always run, the previous not.
When i define only one, it always run.

I try to use shim in requrie to have a one global fauxServer for each mocks but it doesnt work.:

```
shim:{ 
    fauxServer: { 
        deps['backbone'], 
        exports: 'fauxServer' 
    }
}
```

I dont know where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [answer](https://github.com/biril/backbone-faux-server/issues/9#issuecomment-27356982)

1. update the lib version of faux-server to at least 0.9.3
2. You dont need the shim - faux-server is an AMD module
3. Be sure if your route function name is a unique